# std::map::emplace fails to resolve, but insert of rvalue works -- why?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, overload-resolution, emplace

Consider the following attempt to emplace an empty `vector` with a numeric key in a `map`:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main () {
    std::map<size_t, std::vector<size_t>> m;
    m.emplace(42, {});                          // FAILS
    m.insert({42, {}});                         // WORKS
}
```

The call to `emplace` fails to resolve:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<long unsigned int, std::vector<long unsigned int> >::emplace(int, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
     m.emplace(42, {});
                     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/map:61,
                 from map_emplace.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_map.h:574:2: note: candidate: ‘std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::emplace(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {}; _Key = long unsigned int; _Tp = std::vector<long unsigned int>; _Compare = std::less<long unsigned int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, std::vector<long unsigned int> > >; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, std::vector<long unsigned int> > >]’
  emplace(_Args&&... __args)
  ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_map.h:574:2: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
```

Attempting to do the same thing with a vector of vectors works as expected (**EDIT**: not when using `emplace_back`, cf. Bo Persson's answer):

```
    std::vector<std::vector<size_t>> v;
    v.emplace({});           // WORKS -- but does the wrong thing!
    v.emplace_back({});      // FAILS
    v.push_back({{}});       // WORKS
```

My rough understanding of the logic behind `emplace` is that the calls to `emplace` and `insert` should give the same result, the difference being that emplace requires neither move nor copy. For these types, there is not much harm in using the `insert` version, since the contents of the vector would be moved (and in this specific case, the vector is empty, anyway). In general though, why does this fail for `std::map::emplace`? Using GCC 8.1.

Comment: `v.emplace({});` doesn't do what you expect: `{}`is used to construct *`iterator`*.

Comment: Alternatively, you might use `v.emplace_back();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

signature of `map::emplace` is

```
template< class... Args >
std::pair<iterator,bool> emplace( Args&&... args );
```

and `{}` has no type and cannot be deduced.

You might use, for `emplace`:

```
m.emplace(42, std::vector<std::size_t>{});
```

For `insert`, (one of its) signature is:

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );
```

so `{42, {}}` is used to construct `std::pair<const int, std::vector<size_t>>`.

Comment: I take this is somewhat of a shortcoming on part of C++? Because it is *possible* to infer the type of the brace expression and it works fine in `insert`. `emplace` *knows* the type it is trying to construct, so does the outer set of braces in the argument of `insert`.

Comment: @Jonas There's really no way to know, in the general case. The problem here is that [any of the constructors of `std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) is a candidate here and there's quite some nasty stuff in there. In particular, some of the signatures need to accept arbitrary types, with the conversion to the final pair type only happening *inside* the constructor. Since `emplace` is supposed to work with everything that would work with one of the constructors, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

The signatures for `emplace` are different.

For map

```
template< class... Args >
std::pair<iterator,bool> emplace( Args&&... args );
```

vs vector

```
template< class... Args >
iterator emplace( const_iterator pos, Args&&... args );
```

In the `map` case the compiler cannot deduce `Args` from `{}`, so it fails.

For the `vector` it is much easier, as the first parameter in `v.emplace({});`is known to be a `const_iterator`. So `{}` can match a default constructed iterator.

Comment: Good catch. I should have used `emplace_back` for the vector to make it a fair comparison. And sure enough, it fails with a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler is not able to deduce a type for `{}` because `emplace` is a vararg function. Enforce the type and it will work:

```
m.emplace(42, (std::vector<size_t>){});
```